# Mapping a custom domain to your cloud service

Tags: azure, dns, cname, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service on Azure hosted at http://mytest.cloudapp.net and I want to configure it so that it is accessible via http://mytest.mydomain.co.uk subdomain

How can I do this? Is it just a matter of adding a CNAME mytest.mydomain.co.uk to GoDaddy DNS record? I had read that it may require URL forwarding or redirecting when using a subdomain

any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the root domain (http://mydomain.co.uk/), all you need to do is set a CNAME from `mytest.mydomain.co.uk` to `mytest.cloudapp.net`.

If you are using the root domain, you will most likely need to use an A record, as most domain registrars don't support CNAMEs for the root.
Also note that, if you use an A record, you have to be aware that deleting the cloud service will change the IP assigned to it, and you will need to change your DNS records.

Step by step instructions here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Create the CNAME for the domain
2. Update the hostname in your IIS website to answer to that domain in case you have multiple domains or in case there is DNS based configuration your application cares about

That's pretty much it :)

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/ :)